# PySpark application submit error on Yarn cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to submit my PySpark application on cluster mode, and I am getting the below error when submitting the application.

Note: I don't have any dependencies for my app.

```
spark2-submit  --master yarn  --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 8g --num-executors 50 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --py-files filepath
```

I am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the name of the application you want to submit as an argument to spark-submit i.e. add the filename of your application to the end of your spark-submit command.

```
spark2-submit  --master yarn  --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 8g --num-executors 50 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --py-files filepath **filename.py**
```

Comment: I tried that and I am getting below error.                                                                        Cannot load main class from JAR file:path

Comment: Below command i tried                                                                        spark2-submit  --master yarn  --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 8g --num-executors 50 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --py-files filepath    Orders

Comment: What are you passing to **--py-files**? If your application does not have any dependencies, remove the --py-files parameter and pass Orders directly to spark-submit like so:

`spark2-submit  --master yarn  --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 8g --num-executors 50 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false Orders`